# Anaconda以外でのPythonの環境構築について

Tags: python, anaconda

AnacondaのJupyterを使用してPythonでデータ分析、機械学習のモデル作成などをしています。新しいライブラリのインストールやライブラリのアップデートで会社のプロキシで引っかかって、うまくインストールできません。よって、非常に面倒な方法でライブラリのインストールをしています。

Anacondaのように環境構築がしやすくて、ライブラリもある程度デフォルトでインストールされていて、且つ専用のレポジトリを経由しないでインストールが簡単にできるようなツールはありませんでしょうか？

因みにAWSのSage MakerやGoogle Colaboratoryなどのクラウドサービスも使用を禁止されています。

ご回答お願いします。

Comment: `.condarc`にproxyの設定をするだけではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: 私も「プロキシ」には苦労しています。「プロキシで引っかかって」を解消するための質問をしてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。.condarcで試してみます。